# How to get thing from json in d3 tree

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to improve [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) graph visualisation with d3 lib

I'm using json like this

```
    {"name": "START", "children": [{"name": "1", "children": [], "state": ["(free left)", "(free right)"]}], "state": ["(free up)", "(free down)"]}
```

And I need to show the "state" information about node on click. For now it doesn't matter how, alert() for example.

How should I change click() function? What should I use?

Comment: Well, since the click function toggles the nodes, you should decide if you want this behavior or not and if not, then change the click function to something like `function click(d){alert(d.state); // or alert(d.data.state) I don't remember which one it is};`. If you need the toggling, then maybe use another event? E.g. on contextmenu? It is up to what you want the outcome to be.

Comment: Another idea, if you don't want to remove the toggling, is to show the information in a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I simply wasn't thinking about this. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped :)